# 802.11g on 100 Mbps connection

Tags: wireless-router, internet-connection

I recently bought a router on sale and later realized that it is 802.11g. My internet connection is rated 100 Mbps. So, I guess I am losing Mbps over the wireless. But how do I know how much I am losing?

Comment: 100Mbps is not your internet connection, if anything it's your LAN(wireless/WLAN aside).

Comment: @barlop Incorrect to say it is *definitely* not, though. It's certainly possible, and actually quite common in many countries.

Comment: @Bob oh but do you have a link to show that?

Comment: @barlop Why would I need a link? Go take a look for yourself. Pretty much any FTTP connection is capable of that throughput, as are most HFC and similar networks. In many European countries, such connections are quite common - and it's certainly not unheard of in other places, enough so that it's wrong to just declare that 100Mbit/s is definitely not their ISP-advertised connection speed. You can take my word for it or you can go look it up.

Comment: @Bob yes perhaps 'oh' wasn't' clear enough. I accept that correction.  I see for FTTP.. I wasn't up to date with that

Answer (score 3):

Get an empirical test of your network speed from [Ookla](http://www.speedtest.net/about.php). Or your Internet Service Provider (ISP) may have a speed test that gives more accurate results (e.g. google "comcast speed test").

Compare the results from speed tests between a wired connection and a WiFi connection. If the results of the wired connection are significantly less than 100 Mb/s that likely means one or more of:

1. your laptop is the bottleneck
2. the 100 Mb/s your ISP advertises is the best-possible-case bandwidth and you ain't gettin' that right now (a common occurrence with shared-branch cable in US suburbs, especially after school lets out)
3. other (time for you to dig deeper and ask a new question)

If the results of the WiFi speed test results are anywhere near wired connection speed, you win. Quit while you're ahead. If the WiFi speed test results approach 54 Mb/s, that's the top speed of 803.11g. WiFi speed test results significantly lower than the wired results and 54 Mb/s could be caused by (in decreasing order of likelyhood):

- poor WiFi signal strength
- WiFi channel conflicts
- poorly performing WiFi driver
- other

Answer (score 1):

You're losing at least 46 Mbps.

Your internet connection is being throttled from 100 Mbps down to the max throughput of 802.11g standard, which is 54 MBps. With overhead and signal quality variables, it will be less, adding to your bottleneck.

I found that pretty quickly [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=802.11g%20max%20speed)...

---

If you need an exact measurement (which would factor in any overhead and signal quality as DanielB pointed out), you could run a [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/) and subtract it from your ISP's rated speed.

Comment: This is too simple a calculation. You have to account for overhead and signal quality. At the very most, 11g provides 25 MBit/s of user data bandwidth.

Comment: @DanielB If he wanted an exact measurement he could simply run a SpeedTest and subtract it from 100. I added that to my answer.

Comment: I'm not even talking about measurements. It's physically impossible to achieve 54 MBit/s user data throughput. So, to put it simply: Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @DanielB The question is "how do I know how much I am losing?". To get the correct answer, you can go with "at least 46 Mbps", in which you are correct in saying it's much more with overhead. Or you could go with a measurement to calculate loss. There's no way I can deduce his loss since I'm not at his house. Sorry.